# how to convert column's value like ALL_TAB_COLUMNS's HIGH_VALUE format

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert column's value like oracle `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`'s `(Low)HIGH_VALUE` format.

what function should it call? thanks.

ps. `HIGH_VALUE`'s type is `RAW(32)`

input :

```
select somefuntion('xxxooo') from dual
```

expect:

```
7878786F6F6F
```

---

I had read oracle web document: [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277)

Comment: Does not make sense, "xxxooo" to  "32C1A1234234A"?

Comment: `32C1A1234234A...` is RAW(32) type,'xxxooo' is varchar type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [the `utl_raw.cast_to_raw()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-E837A246-2D2A-47C4-A2F3-29735F596CE1):

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_raw('xxxooo') from dual;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('XXXOOO')
-----------------------------
7878786F6F6F
```

Which doesn't match your example output for that made-up input, but you seem to have made up the output too.

As a demo:

```
create table t42(str) as
select 'xxxooo' from dual;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T42');

select high_value from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T42' and column_name = 'STR';

HIGH_VALUE                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------
7878786F6F6F

select utl_raw.cast_to_raw(max(str)) from t42;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(MAX(STR))
-----------------------------
7878786F6F6F
```

Comment: @Alex Poole: What does the `str` in your your `create table` statement do?

Comment: @wolφi - it creates a column called `str`...? The data type is just inferred from the CTAS query; in this case the table has a single column `STR CHAR(6)`, because that is the type and length of the only value I gave. If I'd given several values (via `union all`) with different lengths it would have made it `VARCHAR2` with size of the longest string I used.

Comment: @wolφi - [a quick demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51d732335de2f71b07d7e84b8b3424fd). You can omit the column name list and set those via column aliases in the query too ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a502aee8ddff9f61470a9258149a75fc)), a bit like CTEs.

Comment: @Alex Poole: That's what I did for years. Your version with the names in the `CREATE` is very neat and clear.